# not seeing changes after publishing changes

Tags: asp.net, iis

i have an asp.net 2.0 site which is compiled and has been put in the IIS virtual directory
however the new changes cant be seen by some users, and some other users can see the new changes on the web site, i have tried deleting cache and cleaning internet settings and trying with mozilla and chrome and still cant see the new changes.

we also tried cleaning the connection pool on iis.

is there anything more i can possibly do?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: If it's some users but not others, that sounds like caching, even though you're tried clearing cache. Is there a proxy server around? Maybe it's doing the caching.

Comment: yes, the company has a proxy installed on all computers!

Comment: Then maybe the proxy server is caching the pages. Find out from your networking people what the cache duration is for the proxy server(s), then wait that long and see if the problem clears up.

Comment: the admin of networking told me that proxy does not cache anything, but he told me that maybe has something to do with iis...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, the server was being split in two machines, and when the server admin updated files only did in one of the servers, not both, now both are updated and running ok, thanks every one for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you confirmed that the machines are hitting the right server?  Ping the URL from the "bad" machines and see what it resolves to.

Comment: yes, it is the same url, we also instead of using the url used the ip corresponding to the server

Answer (score 1):

The javascript changes may need browsers to download newer script which was published. (Cached javascript might be older)

For session based changes, if users retained older session, the changes **may** not reflect until they restart the session.

Comment: how can i restart the session?
we tried a pool restart on iis but i didnt work, because the change has been made, it is confirmed, but on machines that used the older webpage are not seeing the change, only on the ones that have never used the web page.

Comment: I am not sure how you are initializing sessions, but if changes you want to see when a fresh session is initialized, the users won't be able to see those changes until they logout(explicitely) or they restart the browser.

Comment: we already tried what you say and still :/
what worries me is that the part that cant see changes is a query made to the oracle DB, it shows developer data, and not the real data.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try (if Bill Gregg's suggestion doesn't work):

1) Bounce the web server services.

2) Download a freeware app called CCLEANER (formerly called Crap Cleaner....it was seriously called that).  This app (when configured correctly) will clean all the junk web files off client machines.

Comment: i cant install programs on my computer :/ company politics